# The figure for X was double that of Y or that for Y ("that of" vs "that for")?

Tags: prepositions

In the context of talking about statistics of two countries, which one is correct?

I have hear "that of" a lot but I have not heard "that for" yet, but in here if we want to stick with the expression "The figure for something" and just replace "the figure" with "that" I don't know what preposition to use. Also, as far as I know, I cannot change it to "The figure of the USA ..." and then easily go for "that of" (if I am not mistaken, I cannot say "the figure *of* the USA").

> 1 The figure for the USA was double that *of* China.

> 2 The figure for the USA was double that *for* China.

Comment: [Google's Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=double+that+of+China%2Cdouble+that+for+China&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) suggests we *only* say "*double that **of** China*"

Comment: A single court in London has a backlog of delayed cases almost double that for the whole of Wales, warns the city's victims' commissioner (The Daily Telegraph)  Vietnam’s national freight task proportion is more than double that for China, the United States, and the European Union (World Bank)

Comment: Two seemingly contradictory comments without in-depth explanation   :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your examples are correct and sound natural.

With prepositions, explanations are always difficult.

For example, whilst:

*"The figure **for** the USA was double that of China."*

is fine,

*"The figure **of** the USA was double that of China."*

does not sound natural.

Comment: Remember that with languages, people use them in a certain way and then grammarians (and punctuation prescribers) attempt to retro-fit rules to actual use.